# Content Resolver not updating throughout whole app

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I am trying to figure out how to update the content resolver, I have looked at many questions about this and have tried all the possible solutions I have come accross and none of them seem to work.

I am successfully deleting the album art work using the following code:

```
    public void deleteAlbumArt(String albumId){

    Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

    getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, Integer.valueOf(albumId)), null, null);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.deletedartwork), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    getActivity().getContentResolver().notifyChange(sArtworkUri, null);

    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, null, this);

}
```

And for some reason, using the following code as you can see above doesn't update the content resolver completely throughout the entirety of my application, only for the fragment I am using this code within.

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().notifyChange(sArtworkUri, null);
```

Am I doing something wrong here? How can I completely notify the Content Resolver through the whole of my app.

I am having to un-install my app and then re-install it for my the Content Resolver to update completely throughout my app.

thanks.

Comment: who do you want to notify?

Comment: That the album art has been deleted

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do with the following code "getActivity().getContentResolver().notifyChange(sArtworkUri, null);"

Comment: who do you want to notify? who should get that notification?

Comment: I don't think you're understanding my question.

Comment: why do you want to call notifyChange? it notifies the observers. so who is an observer?

Comment: Do I need to add an observer?

Comment: with no observers what is the point of calling `notifyChange`? (you shout but no one listens) btw the std ContentProvider in 99% do that when you call `delete` so only add an observer

Comment: I don't know. I thought that calling notifyChange would then notify the ContentResolver that changes have been made therefor updating it telling it that something has been deleted.

Comment: btw what loader are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86774/discussion-between-jack-and-pskink).